# Not able to open Eclipse after uninstalling the Java EE

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-jdt

I am getting error after uninstalling the Java EE from the eclipse and not able to open the eclipse.

The log error is:

```
!SESSION 2013-05-26 17:17:52.625 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=
java.version=1.7.0_01
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product     org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-05-26 17:18:12.703
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the    org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
at  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

And the config.ini

```
#This configuration file was written by:   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
#Sun May 26 14:04:02 GMT+05:30 2013
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=
eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.jee
osgi.instance.area.default=
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.0.v20110613.jar
equinox.use.ds=
eclipse.buildId=
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20110502- 1955.jar@4,reference\:file\:com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_21.1.0.v201302060044-569685.jar@4,reference\:file\:com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package_21.1.0.v201302060044-569685/@4,reference\:file\:com.android.ide.eclipse.base_21.1.0.v201302060044-569685.jar@4,reference\:file\:com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_21.1.0.v201302060044-569685.jar@4,reference\:file\:com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger_21.1.0.v201302060044-569685.jar@4,reference\:file\:com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer_21.1.0.v201302060044-569685.jar@4,reference\:file\:com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk_21.1.0.v201302060044-569685.jar@4,reference\:file\:com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview_21.1.0.v201302060044-569685.jar@4,reference\:file\:com.googlecode.jslint4java_1.0.0.201207042009.jar@4,reference\:file\:com.googlecode.jslint4java.eclipse_1.0.1.201207042009/@4,reference\:file\:com.googlecode.jslint4java.eclipse.ui_1.0.0.201207042009/@4,reference\:file\:com.ibm.icu_4.4.2.v20110208.jar@4,reference\:file\:com.mds.apg_1.2.91.201207042009.jar@4,reference\:file\:javax.servlet_2.5.0.v201103041518.jar@4,reference\:file\:javax.xml_1.3.4.v201005080400.jar@4,reference\:file\:net.sourceforge.keytool.plugin_1.4.2/@4,reference\:file\:org.apache.lucene_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.apache.lucene.analysis_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.apache.lucene.highlighter_2.9.1.v20100421-0704.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.apache.lucene.memory_2.9.1.v20100421-0704.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.apache.lucene.misc_2.9.1.v20100421-0704.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.apache.lucene.queries_2.9.1.v20100421-0704.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.apache.lucene.snowball_2.9.1.v20100421-0704.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.apache.lucene.spellchecker_2.9.1.v20100421-0704.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.apache.xerces_2.9.0.v201101211617.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.apache.xml.resolver_1.2.0.v201005080400.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.apache.xml.serializer_2.7.1.v201005080400.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ant.core_3.2.300.v20110511.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt_8.0.2.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.codan.checkers_1.0.1.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.codan.checkers.ui_1.0.0.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core_2.0.0.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.cxx_1.0.0.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.codan.ui_2.0.1.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.codan.ui.cxx_2.0.0.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.core_5.3.2.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.core.win32_5.2.0.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.core.win32.x86_5.2.0.201202111925/@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core_7.1.0.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.debug.mi.core_7.1.1.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.debug.mi.ui_6.1.1.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui_7.1.2.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user_5.1.1.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.dsf_2.2.0.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb_4.0.2.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.ui_2.2.1.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.ui_2.2.1.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.gdb_7.0.0.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.gdb.ui_7.0.0.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.launch_7.0.0.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.make.core_7.1.2.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.make.ui_7.1.2.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core_8.0.2.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.gnu.ui_8.0.2.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.ui_8.0.2.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.cdt.ui_5.3.2.201202111925.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.compare_3.5.200.I20110525-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.compare.core_3.5.200.I20110208-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.core.commands_3.6.0.I20110111-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.4.100.v20110423-0524.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.core.databinding_1.4.0.I20110111-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable_1.4.0.I20110222-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.core.databinding.property_1.4.0.I20110222-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.core.expressions_3.4.300.v20110228.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.core.filebuffers_3.5.200.v20110505-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.core.filesystem_1.3.100.v20110423-0524.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.5.100.v20110404.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.core.resources_3.7.100.v20110510-0712.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.7.0.v20110110.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth_3.2.200.v20110110.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.core.variables_3.2.500.v20110511.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.debug.core_3.7.0.v20110518.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.debug.ui_3.7.0.v20110518.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.emf.common_2.7.0.v20120127-1122.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.7.0.v20120127-1122.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change_2.7.1.v20120127-1122.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.7.0.v20120127-1122.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.emf.edit_2.7.2.v20120130-0943.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.100.v20110321.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.0.v20110523.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin_2.0.0.v20110502-1955.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin.equinox_1.0.300.v20110506.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_2.0.100.v20110502.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.200.v20110502.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core_2.1.0.v20110502-1955.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine_2.1.0.v20110511.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata_2.1.0.v20110510.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository_1.2.0.v20110511-1359.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository_2.1.0.v20110601.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.4.0.v20110502.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.100.v20110502.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.security_1.1.0.v20110502.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator_2.0.0.v20110502-1955.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.help_3.5.100.v20110426.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.0.v201106131736.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.100.v20110425.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.jdt_3.7.0.v201106131736.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.7.0.v_B61.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation_1.4.0.v20110505-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.jdt.debug_3.7.0.v20110509/@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_3.6.0.v20110512.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.jdt.junit_3.7.0.v20110505-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core_3.7.0.v20110518-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime_3.4.300.v20110505-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.jdt.launching_3.6.0.v20110509.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.jdt.ui_3.7.0.v20110531-1200.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.jem.util_2.1.100.v201103021400.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.jface_3.7.0.I20110522-1430.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.jface.databinding_1.5.0.I20100907-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.jface.text_3.7.0.v20110505-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring_3.5.200.v20110505-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.6.0.v20110505-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.0.v20110513.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.osgi.util_3.2.200.v20110110.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0.v201106131736/@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.search_3.7.0.v20110505-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.swt_3.7.0.v3735b.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.team.core_3.6.0.I20110525-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.team.ui_3.6.100.I20110525-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.text_3.5.100.v20110505-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ui_3.7.0.I20110602-0100.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ui.browser_3.3.100.v20110426.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_3.4.100.v20110425.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ui.console_3.5.100.v20110511.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ui.editors_3.7.0.v20110517-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ui.forms_3.5.100.v20110425.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ui.ide_3.7.0.I20110519-0100.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ui.intro_3.4.100.v20110425.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.500.v20110510/@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ui.navigator_3.5.100.I20110524-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources_3.4.300.I20110421-1800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ui.views_3.6.0.I20110412-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed_3.5.200.I20110201-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.7.0.I20110519-0100.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor_3.7.0.v20110505-0800.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.common.core_1.2.0.v200908252030.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.common.emf_1.2.100.v201101101900.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.common.emfworkbench.integration_1.2.101.v201107140600.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.common.environment_1.0.400.v200912181832.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks_1.2.102.v201201190400.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core_1.4.201.v201201101553.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.common.ui_1.1.500.v200911190730.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver_1.1.401.v201004280700.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core_1.1.102.v201111090634.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.manipulation_1.0.300.v201104272153.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui_1.1.102.v201201131900.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.sse.core_1.1.602.v201112071516.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui_1.3.2.v201201041522.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.validation_1.2.303.v201202090300.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.xml.core_1.1.602.v201201091944.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui_1.1.202.v201112071516.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.junit_3.8.2.v3_8_2_v20100427-1100/@4,reference\:file\:org.mortbay.jetty.server_6.1.23.v201012071420.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.mortbay.jetty.util_6.1.23.v201012071420.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.mozilla.javascript_1.7.2.v201005080400.jar@4,reference\:file\:overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay_21.1.0.v201302060044-569685.jar@4
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:../../../../developing%20tools/eclipse-jee-indigo-  win32/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
eclipse.product=
osgi.splashPath=
osgi.framework.extensions=
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
eclipse.application=
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
Dosgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@
```

Comment: start eclipse with "-console -consoleLog" args and when started, type "ss" and enter. This will show you not resolved bundles

Comment: also, try to remove this line: "eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.jee"

Comment: @AlexStamper how i start eclipse with ..args..

Comment: how to disable the java EE related in the eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Just download [a new eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) with the features you need and don't try to fix your broken eclipse. You can waste too much time trying this.